# How come my Azure timer function app stops firing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure timer function app that fires every five minutes

I have found this very hit and miss after deploying.  It either starts firing or it doesn't.  It if doesn't fire then no matter what I do I cannot seem to get it to fire.

I have tried restarting and refreshing the function in the portal

It is running on a S1 App service plan (that also has three other func apps on it)

My timer cron expression is * */5 * * *

Comment: AlwaysOn is enabled? Does it start firing again after a while? Like after an hour or so?

Comment: yep  always on is enabled.  No it doesn't seem to fire up after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3024) relating the same.

> There is an issue right now if you deploy timer based functions that
> are disabled via app setting then change the app setting to enable
> them. To work around until the fix is made you should click the
> 'refresh' button in the Azure portal after changing app settings used
> for disabling functions.

Comment: I have refreshed on the func app overview screen and also where you can 'Monitor' the function but hasn't helped

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Azure Timer trigger Functions will fail to fire unless you use the B1 or higher app service plan. They should work in the free or shared plans ( docs say so ) but mine keep failing. Hopefully Microsoft will address this at some point.

Comment: Its on a S1 plan which I believe is higher although I just realised there are 3 other function apps utilising the same plan - would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up redeploying all the components in the resource group again and then it started to fire.  It is even firing on the basic consumption plan now so not sure what happened